# Problem with scrollview of android Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I am working with scrollview in my xml file, but this element does not scroll. I don't know why. When I run the app, I am creating it all. It is okay, but no all textviews can be seen, but the scroll does not work for the other textviews. Here is my xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activities.MostrarAnuncioEspecifico"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewAnuncioEspecifico"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="228dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:entries="@array/lisss"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


</ListView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="501dp"

    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="DESCRIPCION"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="ladescripcion"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="INFORMACION DEL INMUEBLE"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Estado del inmueble:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView14" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Tipo de imueble:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView17" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Cantidad de pisos:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView18" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Cantidad de habitaciones:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView19" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Cantidad de baños: "
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView20" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Garaje:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView21" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Alcantarillado:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView22" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="108dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="108dp"
            android:text="elestadodelinmueble"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView17"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView17" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="135dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"
            android:text="eltipoinmueble"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView18"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView25" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="122dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="122dp"
            android:text="elcantidadpisos"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView19"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView26" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView28"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:text="elcantidadhabitaciones"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView20"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView27" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView29"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="114dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="114dp"
            android:text="elcantidadbaño"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView21"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView28" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView30"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="195dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="195dp"
            android:text="elgaraje"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView22"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView29" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="149dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="149dp"
            android:text="elalcantarillado"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView23"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView30" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Precio:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView23" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="196dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="196dp"
            android:text="elprecio"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView32"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView31" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView34"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Superficie:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView32" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView35"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="172dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="172dp"
            android:text="lasuperficie"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView34"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView33" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView36"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Zona:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView34" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView37"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="203dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="203dp"
            android:text="lazona"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView36"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView35" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView38"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="144dp"
            android:text="eldepartamento"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView39"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView37" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView39"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:text="Departamento:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView36" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView40"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="DETALLES ADICIONALES"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView39" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView41"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Eldetalleadicional"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView40" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView42"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="DIRECCION"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView41" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView43"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Ladireccion"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView42" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="VER TRUEQUE"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView43" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="VER INFORMACION DEL VENDEDOR"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

[like this is how the app works without scrolling working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nigoe.png)

If anybody want more details I can give it.

Answer (score 0):

make linear layout inside scroll view and 
inside linear layout put  `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`

Comment: i can help with team viewer

Comment: thanks friend but it is working now the problem is in loyout_height we have to put wrap content :). thanks you.